# How to use the write() system call in C++?

Tags: c++

I am a beginner in C++ and I want to know how to use the write() system call in C++ instead of using cout for my success and error messages.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int rename(const char *oldpath, const char *newpath);

int main()
{
  int result;
  char oldpath[] = "oldfile.cpp";
  char newpath[] = "newfile.cpp";
  result = rename(oldpath, newpath);

  if (result == 0)
    {
      cout << "File renamed successfully\n";
    }
 else
    {
      cout << "Error renaming the file\n";
    }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What `write()` system call?

Comment: what prevents you from doing it? Start by reading the manual maybe http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html

Comment: Coding in C++ and using `write` is like buying a Lamborghini and pushing it to the shops. Just use streams.

Comment: It is operating system specific. For Linux, read [*Advanced Linux Programming*](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) then [write(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) man page. For POSIX, read the [documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/write.html)

Comment: @NathanOliver I think he means this one: http://codewiki.wikidot.com/c:system-calls:write

Comment: I want to use ssize_t write(int fd, void *buf, size_t count);

Comment: see `mas 2 write` |  and it is in `#include <unistd.h>`

Comment: @xinu11 Your comment about the function you want to use belongs in the question itself. You should edit it in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) [has its own](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io) input/output operation and for the output, the standard is `std::cout`.
But there is a function names `write` in [c](/questions/tagged/c) and also a `write` that uses **file descriptor** : `int`

here is the `man 2 write`

```
WRITE(2)                            Linux Programmer's Manual                            WRITE(2)

NAME
       write - write to a file descriptor

SYNOPSIS
       #include <unistd.h>

       ssize_t write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t count);
```

a *system call* is implemented in the `Linux Kernel`
And the user has no access to it. But A library like `standard C library` or like `GNU C library` wraps system calls that others can use it easily.

See this page: https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/

then go to
2: [System calls](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/dir_section_2.html) documents the system calls provided by the Linux kernel.

then at the bottom you will find [write(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html)

and a simple example is:

```
int fd = open( "file", O_RDONLY );
if( fd == -1 )
{
    perror( "open()" );
    close( fd );
    exit( 1 );
}

char buffer[ 100 ];
ssize_t read_byte;

if( ( read_byte = read( fd, buffer, 100 ) ) == -1 )
{
    perror( "read()" );
    close( fd );
    exit( 1 );
}

if( write( STDOUT_FILENO, buffer, read_byte ) == -1 )
{
    perror( "write()" );
    close( fd );
    exit( 1 );
}

close( fd );
```

and you should use this header files as well:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <stdlib.h>   // exit()
#include <stdio.h>    // for perror()
```

and these functions also is known as **Low-Level I/O** function

Thus depending on what level you are coding, then you should decide to use what functionality is best for you. I do not think [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) programmers use these level for a standard [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) code.

---

A simple screenshot of where is `system-called` located.

[image: system-call]

[source](http://derekmolloy.ie/)